# Renaming nested fields in BigQuery query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Nested fields in BigQuery are selected using the `dot` operator.

I have change-data-captured tables with schemas that have a lot of nested fields. I would like to do something like this:

```
SELECT
   after.name as name, 
   after.age as age,
   after.address as address
FROM [mytable]
```

without having to manually specify the `<root.leaf> as <leaf>` clauses. I'm looking for something like:

```
SELECT after.* as <column suffix> from `mytable`
```

Is this possible?

EDIT: Additional info below

Note that my goal here is to remove the `after` prefix in the field names of the output (i.e. `after.name` or `after_name` becomes `name`).

Comment: Can you clarify what the expected versus actual output is? It's not clear why `after.*` does not give the expected results.

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. Added the info in the description.`after.*` does give me the expected result. but the output column for `after.name` becomes `after_name` and so on. I want the output columns to just be `name`, `age`, `address`, etc. without the `after_` prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanation I see for your problem to exist - is if you are still using BigQuery Legacy SQL. So, yes, in this case you will get below if use just `SELECT field_name.*`

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT user_dim.device_info.*
FROM [firebase-analytics-sample-data:android_dataset.app_events_20160607]
LIMIT 2
```

result will be (i am stripping out most columns and show first two only here)

```sql
Row user_dim_device_info_device_category    user_dim_device_info_mobile_brand_name 
1   mobile                                  BLU      
2   mobile                                  Samsung
```

Whereas in BigQuery Standard SQL you will see below for same query

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT user_dim.device_info.*
FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.android_dataset.app_events_20160607`
LIMIT 2   

Row device_category mobile_brand_name
1   mobile          BLU 
2   mobile          Samsung
```

So, to address your issue  - just "simply" [`migrate to BigQuery Standard SQL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql)